# Integer from base 10 to base 2

Tags: number-theory

I do not understand the next method to tranform an integer from base 10 to base 2. Why is the first residue the last digit in the representation of base 2 and not the first? And so on.

[image]

Comment: try to do the same staying in base 10 ;)

Comment: ...or try the same thing to find the base 2 expansion of 64, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first residue is the result of dividing by $2^1$...  the $n $-th the result of dividing by  $2^n $...  that is the reason. ..

Comment: OK but the most strange thing is: When you go back from base 2 to base 10, then you have to $1*2^{10}....0*2^0$ so why is the last one not $0*2^1$?

Comment: @LeneCoenen it is  (the last on the right )

Comment: But in the first step we divide by 2 and $2^0=1$?

Comment: I do not see the genaral rule: When we look at the first equation: we divide by $2^1$ form base 10 to base 2 and from base 2 to base 10 we multiply by $2^0$. When we look at the second equation: we divide by $2^2$ form base 10 to base 2 and from base 2 to base 10 we multiply by $2^1$

Comment: @LeneCoenen the first place is the ones place, just as with base $10$ or any other base...  when the first power of the base goes in evenly (no remainder ), the first entry is $0$...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71640/discussion-between-chris-custer-and-lene-coenen).